# razor_imu_9dof on ROS Indigo - ImportError: No module named cfg

Tags: ros, imu, razor-imu-9dof

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I'm trying to get the razor_imu_9dof node working on ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.
It is well detected on ttyUSB0 and I can see the data flow with gtkterm.

I installed the package from the repository.
When I run

```
roslaunch razor_imu_9dof razor-pub.launch
```

I got an error saying :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/share/razor_imu_9dof/nodes/imu_node.py", line 40, in <module>
    from razor_imu_9dof.cfg import imuConfig
ImportError: No module named cfg
```

I could get the sensor working well on other ROS versions and different Ubuntu.

Any idea about why this error ?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205998/razor_imu_9dof-on-ros-indigo---importerror:-no-module-named-cfg/) by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 157 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2018-07-03**:
@Cyril_J Did you solve the error? I'm having the same problem. My workaround was to comment out the lines of the node code where a variable of that file is used. Of course, the Dynamic Reconfigure is not available because of that.

**Comment by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) on 2018-07-04**:
At the time I ended up using an older version of the razor_imu_9dof package which just worked fine. But looking at it now, the reason is that you need to build the package with catkin_make in order to generate the files for the dynamic reconfigure. Let me know if it works.

**Comment by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) on 2018-07-04**:
Yeah, it works! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package razor_imu_9dof needs to be build to generate the Dynamic Reconfigure files.

---

Originally posted by [Cyril Jourdan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4040/cyril-jourdan/) with karma: 157 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0